# How can I prove that f is bounded if all I know is that it's defined on an interval and nondecreasing?

Tags: limits

I'm given this:

Suppose f(x) is defined (but not necessarily continuous) on closed interval [a, b] and suppose f is nondecreasing on [a, b]

First I have to show that f is bounded above and below. I feel like the fact that it's not necessarily continuous blows many theorems out of the water.

I also have to show that for arbitrary c $\in$ (a, b), that $\lim \limits_{x \to c^-}$f(x) and $\lim \limits_{x \to c^+}$f(x) both exist and that $\lim \limits_{x \to c^-}$f(x) $\le$ f(c) $\le$ $\lim \limits_{x \to c^+}$f(x). Any pointers on that?

Comment: Please see my expanded [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2489775).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ then in particular it is defined at $a$ and at $b$.

And it is non-decreasing, so
it must be not less than $f(a)$ and not greater than $f(b)$, so these two values are bounds, and actually: extremums of the function over the interval.

As for $c \in (a,b)$, the value $f(c)$ is an upper bound, and more specifically a supremum, and even more: the maximum of $f$ over $[a,c]$, and similary it is a lower bound, infimum and minimum of $f$ over $[c,b]$.

Now consider the interval $(a,c)$. Its image $f(a,c)$ is bounded from above by $f(c)$ and non-empty. That implies there exists a lowest upper bounding, that is a supremum $s$ of $f$ over the range: $$s=\sup_{x\in(a,c)}f(x)$$ There are two possibilities: either $f$ reaches that supremum, or not.

1. If it does, then there exists some $d\in(a,c)$ such that $f(d)=s$. But $f$ is non-decreasing, so for all $x>d$ must be $f(x)\ge f(d)=s$. On the other hand, however, $s$ is supremum, hence for all $x\in(d,c)$ must be $f(x)\le s$. As a result of conjunction $$\forall_{ x\in(d,c)}\ f(x)=s$$
   That in turn implies $$\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x) = s$$ which must not be greater than $f(c)$ due to non-decreasing of $f$. Hence $$\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x) \le f(c)$$
2. If $f$ does not reach $s$ on $(d,c)$, it must approach it – supremum is defined as the least upper bound, hence there is no smaller upper bound than $s$. In other words, on $(d,c)$ function $f$ exceeds all $q<s$: $$\forall(q<s)\,\exists(p\in(d,c)) \  f(p)>q$$ Of course, that implies $f > q$ on the whole interval $(p,c)\subset(d,c)$!
   And this is a clear case of epsilon-delta example of convergence: for arbitrary (arbitraily small) $\epsilon = s-q>0$, there exists such (small enough) $\delta=c-p$, that if $|x - c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$. Which means $f$ converges to $f(c)$ (from below, of course).

Getting both cases together we conclude that the left-side limit of $f$ at $c$ exists, and it is equal or smaller than $f(c)$: $$\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x) \le f(c)$$

Similary the right-hand limit.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is nondecreasing on $[a,b]$, then $f(a)\leq f(x) \leq f(b)$ when $a\leq x \leq b$, right? So you have lower and upper bounds immediately.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm trying to prove the limits as x approaches c